# How do you connect multiple apps together in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I really have not found any information about this and I am not sure why.  I want to build several independent apps (project tracker, document approval [6-8 different apps here], calendar items, etc) but how do I link them together to work together?  The goal is to create a dashboard system with all of these apps integrated together but if I combine them under one single app it is such a pain to manage with dozens of data connections, pages, and scripts.  Suggestions?

Comment: You could use a custom database that all apps use and provide links to the other apps from within each app. However you may not exactly avoid having lots of data connections within each app since you still need to integrate the data connector to the table that you need to share from one app to another. The main thing that would become more manageable this way is that each app has less page elements to manage so your app load times would greatly improve.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comment from Markus Malessa:

> You could use a custom database that all apps use and provide links to the other apps from within each app.

Data widgets in Google App Maker can be bound or scripted, so a better solution is to create a table with basic information about each app, with columns like [iconText](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline), appName, appURL, and appVersion. Enter a new record for each published app version. The jump-to-app menu can be populated from a script that gets the largest appVersion for each appName.